# Use function without explicit import in Scala

Tags: scala

I like Scala's *sys.error* function - but I want to distinguish two cases: *internal errors* (e.g. database problem) and *user errors* (invalid input).

I tried extending Scala - but it doesn't seem to work:

```
package scala

class UserException(msg: String) extends RuntimeException(msg)

package object err {

    def internal(message: String): Nothing =
        sys.error(message)

    def usr(message: String): Nothing =
        throw new UserException(message)
}
```

**How should I define err.usr() to be able to use it without an explicit import?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, only `scala.Predef` is imported by default and it's not user extensible in any useful way.

Comment: I was afraid of this answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could put these definitions on the package object of *your* package hierarchy. Then, everything on that package will see them without import.